# Magento 2.1 admin logged in issue in session

Tags: admin, session, magento-2.1

If I logged in admin side by chrome.then if when I logged-in successfully in Mozilla for same magento instance in `magento2.1` then I automatically log out in chrome and throw message `Someone logged into this account from another device or browser. Your current session is terminated.`

Why does this happen in Magento 2.1?

Comment: Yes this is for Security Proposed if one user login than other User Login with same id than your current session is terminated.

Comment: Refer this http://www.emagentosupport.com/2018/12/magento-2-admin-login-into-same-account.html May be help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To disable this feature go to

> Stores > Configuration > Advance > Admin > Security

and

change value of ***Admin Account Sharing*** to ***Yes***.

Answer (score 5):

Follow below attached images screenshot to enable admin account sharing options from Magento admin panel.
Either way you can go to Magento 2 admin>

> Store>> Settings>> Configuration >> Advanced >> Admin >> Security and change ADMIN ACCOUNT SHARING Options to YES

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**If you prefer to run commands instead of going to admin panel or changing in database:**

```
php bin/magento config:set admin/security/admin_account_sharing 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can fire direct SQL query in Database as follows:

```
update `core_config_data` SET value = 1 where `path` = 'admin_account_sharing' and `scope` = "default"
```